# JTA transaction with multiple data source in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jta

I have to develop an application which uses two datasources in Spring. The two datasources should be managed by a transaction so that if there are some exceptions happens in one datasource, the other datasource should also roll back. My issume now is that my current implantation with jta does not work. When I tested my code, if the one datasource has error, the other datasource did not roll back. It just commited. 
Here is my configuration file:

```
<bean id="parentDataSource"
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
         abstract="true">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="username" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="firstDataSource" parent="parentDataSource">
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secondDataSource" parent="parentDataSource">
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jtaTransactionManager"  
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
</bean>  

<bean id="customerDAO" class="springapp.datasource.CustomerDAO">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="firstDataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource2">
        <ref local="secondDataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager">
        <ref local="jtaTransactionManager"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The transaction code in the customerDAO is:

```
public class CustomerDAO {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private DataSource dataSource2;
    private JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager;

    public DataSource getDataSource2() {
        return dataSource2;
    }

    public void setDataSource2(DataSource dataSource2) {
        this.dataSource2 = dataSource2;
    }

    public JtaTransactionManager getJtaTransactionManager() {
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }

    public void setJtaTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager) {
        this.jtaTransactionManager = jtaTransactionManager;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void insertItem(Item item){


        TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(jtaTransactionManager);
        tt.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>(){
            @Override
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus arg0) {
                JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
                String sql = "insert into item(name,price) values ('aaaa',11);";
                jt.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jt.update(sql);
                sql = "insert into item(name,price) values ('aaaa',12);";
                jt.setDataSource(dataSource2);
                jt.update(sql);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use XA Data Sources. JDBC Transactions only span a single datasource. To extend the transaction scope to multiple datasources XA Datasources must be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement AbstractRoutingDataSource for handling multiple datasource and datasource connection will be based on your internal setting.